# setting the variable to null when user selects No in the pop up

Tags: angular

I am trying to fix an error in someone else code. I am very new in angular. 
I am trying to open a pop up window when the user clicks on the link button. When the user clicks on link button called "Reject", he gets a confirmation saying Are you sure you want to Reject. If clicked on Yes button then it open the pop up window. Below is the code for Yes and No questions:

```
<div *ngIf="VerifyBatch.PromptStopEnvelope == true">
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
        <span class="information">
          Are you sure you want to {{VerifyBatch.EnvelopeStopAction}} Envelope {{VerifyBatch.SelectedMail.MailNumber}} ?
        </span>
      </i>
    </span>
    <span>
      <button class="appHighPriorityBtn" (click)="InitSelectedMail();VerifyBatch.PromptStopEnvelope = false;openDialog(VerifyBatch.SelectedMail, VerifyBatch.EnvelopeStopAction, 'Envelope')">
        YES
      </button> &nbsp;
      <button class="appBtnConfirmation" (click)="InitSelectedMail();VerifyBatch.PromptStopEnvelope = false">
        NO
      </button>
    </span>
  </div>
```

Please see below image of the yes No confirmation:

[image]

Once I click Yes, I see the below window:

[image]

Above window requires user to enter a code. If I don't enter the code and click on button "Reject envelope" then the pop up window closes and an error message appears on the parent window saying "Please enter the code". Below is the image:

[image]

below is the code for the error. This code is in the pop up window :

```
 <div *ngIf="data.Action == 'Reject'">
            <div class="inputMargin" *ngIf="!data.IsFreeText">
                <mat-form-field class="fullWidth margintop10">
                    <mat-select placeholder="Rejection Code" [(ngModel)]="data.RejectCode" name="rejectionCode">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let rejectionCode of data.RejectionCodesSelect" [value]="rejectionCode.Code">
                            {{rejectionCode.Code}}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
```

Again, I can click on the Reject Link button and the confirmation message appears again asking "Are you sure you want to reject envelope". If I say "No" then the pop up window does not come up, but the old error message that says "Please enter a Rejection code" does not go away. How can I make the message go away if I click on "No" confirmation message?

I know if I nullify these two variable:

```
 this.MailItemValidationErrors = null;
 this.MailValidationErrors = null;
```

in my component file then the message will go away, but I am not sure which function to assign null to these two variables. below is my partial component code:

```
Component({
    selector: 'detach-dialog',
    templateUrl: './detachreason.dialog.component.html',
})
export class DetachDialogComponent {

    constructor(
        public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<DetachDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) { dialogRef.disableClose = true; }

    onNoClick(): void {
      this.dialogRef.close();

  }

}

@Component({
    selector: 'app-verifybatch',
    templateUrl: './verifybatch.component.html'
})

export class VerifybatchComponent implements OnInit {

 openDialog(mailOrItem, action: string, itemType: string): 

// some variables are assigned here

dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(result => {
         // this.RefreshScreen();
          this.MailValidationErrors = null;
          if (result != null) {

        // code here
```

any help will be highly apprecaited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 this.dialogRef.close(valueToReturnFromDialog);
```